# SQL query to account for users with a middle name

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a column called "name" where I store the full name of the user (example: "John Wood" or "John Michael Wood"). I have a query that checks the existence of this user in the database based on its name, example:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE var.name%
```

Where "var.name" is the input from a user looking for this other user in the database. If the user to be looked up is named "John Wood", everything works fine, but if the user has a middle name, "John Michael Wood", the query won't find the user if the string "John Wood" is the searched key.

How can I modify the query to find the user "John Michael Wood" when the search key is "John Wood"? In other words, if the user has a middle name, they should still be found in the database even if their middle name isn't included in the search string.

Comment: Separate the name with the spaces, and requery them in varius `LIKE`... suppose you have an array with the separated names (by space), you need to create a `LIKE` sentence with each array position. and use `LIKE "%your-i-array-position-value%"`

Comment: Or replace all spaces with '%' beforehand. The query would become 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE '%John%Wood%'

Comment: Show us some sample table data and also the expected result. Include Malcolm McDowell, Conan O'Brien, Carl van der Walt and Jonathan Rhys-Davies to make things a bit trickier!

Comment: That kind of design is ill-advised in any relational database system.  Why not Firstname, Middlename, Lastname?  You can't index the last name or even the middle name according to your example, resulting in a full-table scan instead of an index seek.

Comment: @TheWhiteRabbit your solution seems to work fine, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex to solve this problem, replacing the space between the first and last names with something which searches for a space followed by an optional middle name (a set of alphabetic characters) and another space. For example:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE name REGEXP CONCAT('^', REPLACE('John Wood', ' ', ' ([[:alpha:]]+ )?'), '$')
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=f317bbd77c2e11f84f93ddeb66898f00)

```
create table users (id int auto_increment primary key,
                    name varchar(40));
insert into users (name) values
('John Wood'),
('Johnny Wood'),
('John Woodman'),
('John Michael Wood'),
('Michael Wood'),
('John Smith');
```

Output:

```
id  name
1   John Wood
4   John Michael Wood
```

Comment: Your solution seems to work (didn't try it out), but I'm going with the answer provided in the comments.

Comment: @dmc4 the solution in the comments can give you inaccurate results. See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0df561f2481c318cb17cc364dc09906e

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use a full-text index. If you have a full-text index on your `name` column, the query below should return both `'John Wood'` and `'John Michael Wood'`:

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE MATCH(`name`) AGAINST ('John Wood' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
```

Comment: Unfortunately that returns anything that remotely looks like `John Wood` https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=84867375bd606088b0c9c9359ea645e1. Boolean mode works better but doesn't deal with hyphenated surnames or when the first search term is the person's middle name.

Answer (score -1):

You should try this query:
`SELECT * FROM users WHERE name LIKE '%var.name%'`
Now when you search for John this will return all the names having john at any instance in the name string